# Problem converting string to decimal number

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, decimal

Where is the problem with this code?

```
def my_average(*num):
    s, count = 0, 0
    for nums in num:
        if type(nums) == int:
            s += nums

        elif type(nums) == float:
            s += nums

        elif type(nums) == str:
            for k in nums:
                float_num = float(k)
                s += float_num

        count += 1
    return round(s / count, 2)

test_case = (2, 3, 25, '234.123123', 3, 1, 0)
print(my_average(*test_case))
```

> Actually, I wanted to convert the decimal string into a decimal number and use it in my calculations.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What does this program output, and how does it differ from what do you expect it to output?

Comment: `for k in nums:` Why are you looping here again?

Comment: Why not a simple `s += float(nums)`?

Comment: BTW, `for nums in num:` would be clearer as `for num in nums:`.

Comment: `isinstance` would be a better option than `type`. Other things may not have been taken into account. The results of `test_case = (1, 1)` and `test_case = (1, 1, [], [])` are different. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the entire tuple to `float` you can use

```
map(float, test_case)
```

which you can sum with

```
sum(map(float, test_case))
```

and get the average

```
sum(map(float, test_case))/len(test_case)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through each character in the string here: `for k in nums:`, which causes`float(k)` to try to convert the `.` character. Remove it

```
        elif type(nums) == str:
            # for k in nums:
                float_num = float(nums)
                s += float_num
```

Comment: Another problem I have is that if there is a string in the tuple and I want to calculate its length, it gives an error with this method.

Comment: @soft For tuples, you need to manually iterate or parse the string. Please ask a new question with sample data for problems not mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to convert everything to float:

```
def my_average(*args):
    if args:
        return sum(map(float, args)) / len(args)

test_case = (2, 3, 25, '234.123123', 3, 1, 0)
print(my_average(*test_case))
```

**Output:**

```
38.30330328571428
```